# AWS CloudWatch metric math with a cumulative metric's value 30 minutes ago to show rate of change

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a AWS CloudWatch custom metric that represents a cumulative value which continues to increase overtime.  I will add that metric to a dashboard, but I also want to show the rate of change of this metric over the last 30 minutes.  Ideally I would like a function  to return the metric's value from 30 minutes ago and subtract that from the current value.  The "Rate()" function does not seem to help.

I could submit the metrics value a second time with a timestamp that is 30 minutes in the future and subtract these two metrics, but I am hoping for a solution that uses metric math and does not force me to submit another metric.  I can think of other use cases where I might want to do math with metrics from different time periods.
Hope I am just missing something here!

Comment: What type of Dashboard are you using? One generated by Amazon CloudWatch, or is it running on some other software?

Comment: A CloudWatch dashboard.

Answer (score 13):

You can use some arithmetic to obtain the previous value and then you're able to calculate the percentage of change as you want.

The value you want is: `(value_now - value_before) / value_before`

Breaking this into 2 parts:

1. Obtain `value_now - value_before`. This is the *absolute delta* of the values.
2. Obtain `value_before`. This is the value of the metric in the last datapoint.

Assuming that your metric in Cloudwatch is `m`.

### Step 1: The *absolute delta*

The `absolute_delta` can be obtained with: `absolute_delta = RATE(m) * PERIOD(m)`.

### Step 2: The *previous value*

With some arithmetic it is possible to obtain `previous_value`. Given the definition of **absolute delta**:

```
absolute_delta = value_now - value_before
```

Since we have `value_now = m` and `absolute_delta`, then it's a matter of inverting the equation:

```
value_before = value_now - absolute_delta
```

### Final equation

Just plug everything together and you have your final metric:

```
change_percentage = 100 * absolute_delta / value_before
```

## In CloudWatch terms:

[image: cloudwatch metrics definition]

Comment: I'm not sure the calculation of `absolute_delta` is correct, though it may be the best approximation that is possible. Because [`RATE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) is calculated based only on the most recent and previous data points, `RATE(m) * PERIOD(m)` just extrapolates that line segment back to the desired time, regardless of the actual value of `m` at that time.

Comment: You can also use `(DIFF(m) / m) * 100` with the same result.

Answer (score 6):

Metric math function `RATE()` calculates the rate of change per second.

> Returns the rate of change of the metric, per second. This is calculated as the difference between the latest data point value and the previous data point value, divided by the time difference in seconds between the two values.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html

So to get the rate of change for your period you could do this:

```
RATE(m1)*PERIOD(m1)
```

and set the period of the dashboard to the wanted value.

Problem in your case is that you need it for a period of 30 min, I don't think you can set 30 min as period on the CloudWatch dashboard. Closest values would be 15 min or 1 hour.

Comment: Like I said the RATE() function will not help.

Comment: This answer works quite well - use a period over which you want to measure the rate, which has certain limits as mentioned (15 min or 1 hour not 30 min).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Peuchele's comment above, you can use `DIFF()` here instead of `RATE()`.

The only difference is their answer `(DIFF(m) / m) * 100` will give the percentage change relative to the current value of `m`, instead of the percentage change relative to the previous value.

Assuming you want to see what the percentage change is relative to the previous value of `m`, you just need to substitute the denominator `m` for `m - DIFF(m)` which will give you the previous value of `m`.

So, your final CW math expression would be

`(DIFF(m) / (m - DIFF(m))) * 100`